# only solution to wave equation under certain restriction?

Tags: linear-pde, wave-equation

Suppose $u_1, u_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two bounded solutions to the wave equation
\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2u_i = \partial_x^2u_i
\end{equation}
obeying the restriction
$\partial_x \left(u_1^2 + u_2^2\right) = 0$.
Is it so that $u_1$ and $u_2$ must be of the form
\begin{equation}
u_1(x,t)=C_1\sin(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_1) + C_2\cos(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_2(x,t)=\pm \left( C_1\cos(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_1) - C_2\sin(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_2) \right)?
\end{equation} 
I stumbled on this question while studying MHD waves in the nonlinear regime.

Comment: Migrated from Math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077867/only-solution-to-wave-equation-under-certain-restriction

Comment: Take any two functions $f,g$ with $f^2+g^2=\textrm{constant}$, and let $u_1=f(x-t)$, $u_2=g(x-t)$.